# How do I test named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd

I get the following error when testing a named route

```
1) Failure:
test_settings_route(ProjectsControllerTest) [/test/functional/projects_controller_test.rb:15]:
The generated path <"/projects/1/edit"> did not match <"/projects/1/settings">
```

Here's the test and what I put in my routes file

```
# projects_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class ProjectsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
def test_settings_route
  assert_routing '/projects/1/settings', :controller => 'projects', :action => 'edit', :id => '1'
end

# routes.rb
map.settings '/projects/:id/settings', :controller => 'projects', :action => 'edit'
```

With that entry in my routes file my application behaves as expected - which is to render the project's edit template when /projects/1/settings is requested - but I just don't understand how to get my test green.

I've also tried the shoulda macro with the same result

```
should_route :get, "/projects/1/settings", :controller => 'projects', :action => 'edit', :id => '1'
```

Comment: According to the RailsGuide on routing "The routes.rb file is processed from top to bottom when a request comes in. The request will be dispatched to the first matching route."  So you'll probably want to keep your more specific named routes before the more general RESTful routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `map.resources :projects` above my named route in routes.rb. Moving my named route to the top fixed my test.